# How to sort a list in scala

Tags: scala

I am a newbie in scala and I need to sort a very large list with 40000 integers.
The operation is performed many times. So performance is very important.
What is the best method for sorting?

Comment: Did you try something so far ?

Comment: I suggest you do some research and come back with more specific questions. An starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscala%5D+sort

Answer (score 13):

You can sort the list with `List.sortWith()` by providing a relevant function literal. For example, the following code prints all elements of `sorted` list which contains all elements of the `initial` list in alphabetical order of the first character lowercased:

```
val initial = List("doodle", "Cons", "bible", "Army")
val sorted = initial.sortWith((s: String, t: String) 
   => s.charAt(0).toLower < t.charAt(0).toLower)
println(sorted)
```

Much shorter version will be the following with Scala's *type inference*:

```
val initial = List("doodle", "Cons", "bible", "Army")
val sorted = initial.sortWith((s, t) => s.charAt(0).toLower < t.charAt(0).toLower)
println(sorted)
```

For integers there is `List.sorted`, just use this:

```
val list = List(4, 3, 2, 1)
val sortedList = list.sorted
println(sortedList)
```

Answer (score 2):

just check the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sortBy[B](f:A=>B)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering[B]):Repr)

List has several methods for sorting. `myList.sorted` works for types with already defined order (like `Int` or `String` and others). `myList.sortWith` and `myList.sortBy` receive a function that helps defining the order

Also, first link on google for `scala List sort`: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-sort-scala-sequences-seq-list-array-buffer-vector-ordering-ordered

Answer (score 1):

you can use List(1 to 400000).sorted