# How can we sort a list in alphanumeric way in scala

Tags: scala

I have a list `["img10", "img2", "img4", ...]`, I want to sort it and get `["Img1", "Img2", "Img3",...]`. Using sorted the result is `["img1", "img10", "img100", ...]`

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Could you post something you've attempted ?

Comment: Or a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945873/how-to-sort-a-list-in-scala ?

Comment: Will all files have the same prefix? Or will all of them have different prefixed but all will end with a number?

Comment: @brianAgnew, I tried List.sorted and the result is as i said above. @Luis, yes they all have the same prefix and will end with a number, and they have a class of `java.io.File`, sorry I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can have only names matching names like `IMG_1111.JPG`, or regex `\D*\d*\.\w+`, it is possible to sort the sequence with the help of capturing regex groups and then prefixing numbers with a leading space  .

```scala
import scala.jdk.StreamConverters._

val ImageNumberExt = raw"(\D*)(\d{1,10})\.(\w*)".r
Files
  .list(Path.of("/path/to/folder"))
  .toScala(LazyList)
  .map(_.toFile)
  .sortBy { f =>
    f.getName match {
      case ImageNumberExt(stringPrefix, number, ext) =>
        stringPrefix + f"$number%10s" + ext
      case str =>
        str
    }
  }
  .foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually the elements of the list I wanted to sort have a class of `java.io.File`, so when I tried your code it says : No implicit arguments of type: Ordering[Serializable with Comparable[_ >: String with File <: Serializable with Comparable[_ >: String with File]]].

Comment: @Reda20 you have to specify it in your question. How would you expect me to know this? See my edit for changes

Answer (score 0):

Given that all files should have the same prefix and then they will have a numeric part, the best to do is to sort based on that numeric part like this:

```scala
import java.io.File

val files: List[File] = ...

val filesSorted =
  files.sortBy { file =>
    // Tune as needed.
    file.getName.trim.toLowerCase.stripPrefix(prefix = "img").toIntOption
  }
```